# Deprecation notices in every console command following Symfony 5.4 upgrade

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, php-8.1, symfony5.4

I am quite confused by the following deprecation notice in my Symfony 5.4 application.

> The "Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::$defaultName" property
> is considered final. You should not override it in
> "CRMPiccoBundle\Console\Command\Aws\Cognito\CreateUser".

In my code I have the following:

```
class CreateUser extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'crmpiccobundle:aws:cognito:createuser';
```

...which aligns with [the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/console.html#creating-a-command).

The parent Command class looks like this:

```
/**
 * @var string|null The default command name
 */
protected static $defaultName;
```

All my commands are now outputting a deprecation notice, which is not ideal.

```
composer show | grep console
symfony/console                      v5.4.19            Eases the creation of beautiful and testable command line interfaces
```

What am I misunderstanding here? I'm on PHP 8.1.14.

Comment: As you probably also already discovered the $defaultName property is [deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/45361), but I'm also very confused by the deprecation message you're seeing.

Comment: Please share more details. I can't find that error message within Symfony's code

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/45360 is involved here? Do you probably use `symfony/error-handler` v6.1 or later?

Comment: It is puzzling. I made a fresh 5.4.20 app, added a command using static for the name/description and I am not getting any notices.  The message you are showing is not a deprecation notice.  It is an actual warning about overriding final variables.  I think it is just a coincidence that Symfony has deprecated the variables in 6.1.  Is CRMPiccoBundle your bundle?  Double check that UserCommand is extending `Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command` and not some other base command class.  It makes no sense to have final on classes designed to be extended.

Comment: You shouldn't be receiving a deprecation notice for final properties in Symfony 5.4.x, what does `composer show | grep symfony` output?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your comment. I downgrade `symfony/error-handler` and it resolved the problem. I'm not entirely sure what brought in version 6, but a downgrade to v5 has cleared these up for now.

Answer (score 3):

First: **Deprecations are not errors** You are not required to fix anything until you upgrade to Symfony 6. Then you *must* fix the error.

Second, like many documentations, the Symfony docs sometimes lag behind the development. [The new method is documented here](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/console.html#registering-the-command)

So you can switch to using this

```php
#[AsCommand(
    name: 'crmpiccobundle:aws:cognito:createuser',
    description: 'Creates a new user.',
)]
class CreateUser extends Command
{
...
```

Comment: Of course it is not actually a deprecation notice that is being generated.  Your suggestion might make the message go away but what is causing the message is still a bit of a mystery.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although, I don't think anyone said the deprecations were errors, did they? I quite like the `AsCommand` syntax but i'm happy to downgrade `symfony/error-handler` for now.